# Enable http binding in apache

Tags: javascript, apache, http, binding, xmpp

I want to try this AJAX jabber library - http://blog.jwchat.org/jsjac/ and it needs http binding enabled in my Apache. So i tried to uncomment lines with `mod_proxy` and `mod_rewrite` in apache conf. Nothing, I get err msg from jsjac
`An error occured:
Code: 503
Type: cancel
Condition: service-unavailable`

What do I need to do to enable this http binding? I have Apache on `localhost` and I am trying to connect to public jabber server `jabbim.com`. I think it would be something with `<VirtualHost>`, but dunno how to set it. I found this page - http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/bind.html but it didnt helped me much :(

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, you really need just enable `mod_proxy` and then input correct address to bind server, which is in my case `http://bind.jabbim.cz/http-bind/`.